# BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter doesnt work with spring batch 4.2.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, bean-io

I have configured BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter like below and using spring batch 4.2.4

```
@Bean
    public BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter<Transaction> glWriter() {
        BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter<GLTransaction> writer = new BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer .setStreamMapping(new ClassPathResource("mapping.xml"));
        writer .setStreamName("transactionStream");
        writer .setResource(new FileSystemResource("out.csv"));
        return writer ;
    }
```

It fails with error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.<init>(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at org.beanio.spring.BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter$Stream.createBufferedWriter(BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter.java:561)
    at org.beanio.spring.BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter$Stream.open(BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter.java:372)
    at org.beanio.spring.BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter.open(BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter.java:101)`. Any help

Comment: This is usually because of dependencies that come from different versions where the API expect some method signature (what you have above) but the implementation on the classpath doesn't match that signature

Comment: What is `BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter`? Can you share its code?

Comment: BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter is bean-io implementation of ItemWriter ,https://github.com/fubar-coder/beanio/blob/master/src/org/beanio/spring/BeanIOFlatFileItemWriter.java

Comment: looks like Bean-io project is not active and not compatible with spring 4. https://github.com/kevinseim/beanio/issues/22

Comment: ok that's a beanio issue then. Try with the latest Spring Batch 3.0.10 and see if it works. However, Spring Batch 3 is in EOL since January 11th, 2019: https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/11/spring-batch-4-1-1-4-0-2-and-3-0-10-available-now.